# jquery changing clone style changes original style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add change the inline-style property of my html. For this, I cloned a div and append it to another div. I am also trying to display the HTML contents in textarea after stripping the inline-style. Here's my code

```
//Store html in temp div
$("#html_code").clone().appendTo("#temp_html");

//remove style attribute
$("div.animation-1 span.front").removeAttr('style');

//clone this and attach to textarea
var html_extracted = $("#temp_html").clone().html();
$("#show_html").text(unescape(escape(html_extracted)));
```

Here is the `#html_code`:

```
<div id="html_code">
<!--HTML Code-->
    <div class='animation-1'>
        <span id="box" class='letter hidden'>
            <span class='back'>Android</span>
            <span class='front'>T</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the `#temp_html`:

```
<!--Stores cloned html to remove its style-->
<div id="temp_html"></div>
```

Here is the `#show_html`:

```
<!-- HTML Code display -->
<div id ="html-code-area" class="codearea">
    <textarea id="show_html" cols="58" rows="20">
        HTML will be displayed here
    </textarea>        
</div>
```

But when the clone is changed, it changes the original too. Is there a way to change the clone only without changing the original?
Also, the text in textarea keeps adding the same code again and again. How can I replace everything in the textarea with new contents?

Comment: Looks like you'll end up with elements with the same ID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code in a fiddle, - it works as expected with clone(), except that you remove the style attr from both nodes. You should select only the temp html:

```
$("#temp_html div.animation-1 span.front").removeAttr('style');
```

and about replacing the text in the textarea - you need to empty #temp_html before doing a new copy, like this:

```
$('#temp_html').empty();
```

The text inside #show_html is always replaced, it's just that #temp_html had several nodes attached.

here's the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WdTum/3/

Comment: I think that solves the first problem with cloning, but everytime I click a button, the code keeps adding to textarea. I want to replace everything in the textarea with the new content. Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/WdTum/2/

Comment: you just need to empty() #temp_html. I edited the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WdTum/3/ and the answer

Comment: it works only once. When I click the button second time, nothing happens.

Comment: that's because you copy the same content :) if you manually delete the text from the textarea, you will see that it gets cloned and put into the textarea correctly.

what do you want to achieve? What would you like to do on the second click?

Comment: I want to clone, remove attribute and replace everything in the textarea with every button click. Just like the button was behaving before adding empty(). However, I want new contents in text area with every button click.

Comment: ok, but what new content? Right now, you are always getting a new copy of #html_code.

Comment: ok I got it. Actually, the JSFiddle was part of my original project. Its working just fine in my original project. I'll accept your answer now.